# No member named 'setResizeMode' in 'QHeaderView' - Convert Qt 4.7 to Qt 5.8

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I need to **convert Qt legacy code from 4.7 to 5.8**, I have a compilation error in Qt Creator 4.2.1 Clang 7.0(Apple) 64bit.

**Looking in .cpp file**

```
#include "frmMainTableView_UI.h"
#include <QHeaderView>

void frmMainTableView_UI::setupUI(const QMap<int, QString> &columnNames_, bool hasRowLabels_, QWidget *parent_)
{
    widget = new QWidget(parent_);

    layout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
    layout->setSpacing(0);
    layout->setMargin(1);

    frmMainToolbar_UI::setupUI(columnNames_, widget);

    tableSplitter = new QSplitter(widget);

    table = new mpiTableView(hasRowLabels_, widget);
    tableCopy = new QShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_C, table);
    if (!hasRowLabels_)
        table->verticalHeader()->hide();
    table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
    table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    table->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    table->horizontalHeader()->setHighlightSections(false);
    table->verticalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);  // Error convert Qt4 to Qt5 ??
    table->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);  // Error convert Qt4 to Qt5  ??
    tableSplitter->addWidget(table);
    tableSplitter->setStretchFactor(0, 3);

    layout->addWidget(toolbar);
    layout->addWidget(tableSplitter);
}
```

**2 Errors in .cpp**

In file included from ../src/ui/frmMainTableView_UI.cpp:1:
../src/ui/frmMainTableView_UI.h:21:18: **warning** : 'frmMainTableView_UI::setupUI' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
    virtual void setupUI(const QMap &columnNames_, bool hasRowLabels_, QWidget *parent_ = 0);
                 ^

../src/ui/frmMainToolbar_UI.h:31:18: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'frmMainToolbar_UI::setupUI' declared here: different number of parameters (2 vs 3)
    virtual void setupUI(const QMap &columnNames_, QWidget *parent_ = 0);
                 ^

../src/ui/frmMainTableView_UI.cpp:24:30: **error: no member named 'setResizeMode' in 'QHeaderView'** ; did you mean 'sectionResizeMode'?
    table->verticalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);  // JDL Error convert Qt4 to Qt5 ??
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                             sectionResizeMode
/Users/john/Qt/5.8/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qheaderview.h:133:16: note: 'sectionResizeMode' declared here
    ResizeMode sectionResizeMode(int logicalIndex) const;
               ^

../src/ui/frmMainTableView_UI.cpp:25:32: **error: no member named 'setResizeMode' in 'QHeaderView'** ; did you mean 'sectionResizeMode'?
    table->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);  // JDL Error convert Qt4 to Qt5  ??
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               sectionResizeMode
/Users/john/Qt/5.8/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qheaderview.h:133:16: note: 'sectionResizeMode' declared here
    ResizeMode sectionResizeMode(int logicalIndex) const;
               ^

**1 warning and 2 errors generated**
make: *** [frmMainTableView_UI.o] Error 1
18:29:48: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project mypersonalindex (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"

The Qt5 Docs mentioned **Obsolete Members for QHeaderView**
The following members of class QHeaderView are obsolete. They are provided to keep old source code working. We strongly advise against using them in new code.

**(obsolete) void setResizeMode(ResizeMode mode)**

My C++ skill is pretty limited, do you see any minor tweaks that could convert this from Qt4 to Qt5. ... so what is the replacement?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you need to replace two obsolete lines:

```
table->verticalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);  
table->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

with the following Qt 5 code:

```
table->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents); 
table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

See the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode).